# Axis/vector notation in Minkowski diagrams

Tags: special-relativity, notation

Learning special relativity and working with Minkowski diagrams for a while now i am still trying to get my head around some oddity.

From my understanding time can often be seen as the dependent variable in those diagrams, so why put it to the vertical axis? What confuses me even more is the apparent convention to denote a point in space time $(t,x)$ even though $x$ is on the horizontal and $t$ is on the vertical axis, so the usual notation would be to refer to that vector as $(x, t)$.

Are there mostly historical reasons or why is it beneficial to use this notation and to violate usual conventions?

Comment: Writing $(t,x)$ rather than $(x,t)$ is not really a totally standardized convention. Different writers do it one way or the other. The convention of drawing $t$ vertically appears to be at least as old as Minkowski's 1909 paper "Space and Time:" https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Space_and_Time_(Prasad) . *From my understanding time can often be seen as the dependent variable in those diagrams, so why put it to the vertical axis?* Spacetime diagrams aren't primarily about graphing a function showing the position of a particle as a function of time. Conceptually, they represent the whole universe.

Comment: For a possible historical reason see my answer to a similar question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666612/1648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In special relativity, one deals instead with 4-vectors rather than the 3-vectors to which you're probably accustomed.  In 4-vector notation, you have $x^n = [x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3]$, where the superscripts are *not* exponents, but rather indices of a rank 1 tensor (if you read about this, note that a rank 1 tensor with a *raised* index is a vector, whereas a similar tensor with a *lowered* index is a covector, or dual vector).
Expressed in normal Cartesian coordinates, the 4-vector is $\hat x= [ct, x, y, z]$.

In practice, the axes on a Minkowski diagram may be interchanged without any problems - the important property is the asymptote $ct = x$, which denotes the worldline of massless particles.

Comment: I don't see how the first paragraph of your answer addresses my question. No doubt you can change axis declaration and component order without altering the theory, the question is why do we deviate from the standard?

Comment: The 4-vector always has the time component first, followed by spacial components.  The convention for denoting a point in spacetime is actually $P = [ct, x, y,z]$, and $y$ and $z$ are both $0$ on the flat path-time diagram. This is why it's denoted $[t,x]$, even though $x$ is on the horizontal, which is completely arbitrary.

Comment: I guess i put too much thought into one little aspect of a larger theory which is completely symmetric in that regard. Thanks for guiding me into the right direction!