# Why are the axes in Minkowski diagrams swapped when comparing with diagrams in classical kinematics?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, conventions

In diagrams in classical kinematics, the time coordinate $t$ is drawn horizontally and the spatial coordinate $x$ is drawn vertically.

Why are Minkowski diagrams drawn the other way round?

In classical kinematics, we like to picture position as a function of time, so having time on the horizontal axis in a diagram simply corresponds to the usual way we draw the graph of a function.

I get that in relativity, position and time are on equal footing, so that the functional aspect may be deemphasized. But since it is a pretty big hurdle to compare relativistic kinematics to classical kinematics if we always have to flip the diagrams in our heads, I would expect that this would be only done if there are some striking advantages. However, I couldn't think of any.

What's even more strange is that we still write vectors as $(ct,x)$ instead of $(x, ct)$. So we are also making it harder to apply visual intuitions based on the usual conventions in linear algebra (like picturing the action of a familiar matrix on a vector). Maybe the conventions in linear algebra are actually more recent than the conventions of special relativity.

**edit:** Although the other question has an accepted answer, it does not answer the question of *why* the convention from classical kinematics was discontinued. It simply reiterates that it *is* a convention (and a comment expands that this convention can be traced at least to a 1909 paper by Minkowski himself).

Comment: There has been a similar question which didn't lead to a satisfatory answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278540/

Comment: I guess it kinda makes more sense in diagrams that have two spatial components, so you have a stack of horizontal planes of simultaneity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axis/vector notation in Minkowski diagrams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278540/)

Comment: @BenCrowell: I already referenced this question in my first comment. Now I am supposed to chose between "That solved my question" and "No, my question is different." My question is very similar but the answer over there is not satisfactory to me. So neither of them applies and still I am in need of an answer. Is stackexchange not suited for different user having different standards for answers?

Comment: @Marc: If you're just not satisfied with the existing answers to that question, the thing to do is to put a bounty on it.

Comment: @BenCrowell: Thanks for mentioning it. I wasn't aware that I could start bounties for questions which are posed by others or for questions which already have an accepted answer. It's a subotimal solution however because of the reputation loss.

Comment: For a possible historical reason see my answer to a similar question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666612/1648

Comment: @asmaier: Thanks, that's the first idea which makes sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

It's mainly a matter of aesthetics, and it's more natural (at least in my opinion). A special relativity course typically starts with a *Gedankenexperiment* involving two observers moving with respect to each other; the canonical example is that of a moving train and a platform. The reference frames of these observers can be drawn like this

[image]

where the direction of motion is along the $x$-axis. From this, it's fairly straightforward to then represent both reference frames in a single spacetime diagram, where the $x$-axis remains horizontal. One can also keep the $y$-axis, so that the spacial coordinates in the rest frame lie in horizontal planes of equal time. In addition, light-cones are vertical. I'd argue that this looks better than vertical space axes and horizontal light cones.

[image]

It also highlights a conceptual difference with classical mechanics. In the latter, time is agreed upon by all observers, so it makes sense to write a path as a function $x(t)$, i.e.  time is a parameter. In special relativity however, the flow of time depends on the reference frame, and time gets upgraded to an additional coordinate, placed on the same footing as the spatial coordinates. A path is therefore more conveniently written as a parametrized curve of the form $(t(\lambda), x(\lambda))$. In other words, a spacetime diagram is a depiction of a *coordinate space*, rather than the graph of functions.

Regarding the convention $(ct,x,y,z)$, this is not universal. I've seen textbooks where $(x,y,z,ct)$ is used. But $(ct,x,y,z)$ is more convenient, because it's often rewritten as $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, and physicists regularly switch between both notations.

Are these big hurdles for students? I don't think so, compared with more abstract representations like phase-space diagrams or general coordinate transformations. In any case, it is important for students to learn that visual diagrams are a tool, and that different problems often suggest different tools. Likewise, students should become comfortable with switching between different notational conventions. Learning physics is all about expanding your toolbox.